# Is Apache http server 2.5/2.6 available now?

Tags: apache

I want to keep the my Apache HTTP server to its latest version. So I check https://httpd.apache.org/ and it says  2.4.48 is the latest version. I also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server#Versions and it says the latest version is 2.4.48 (June 1, 2021; 2 months ago[2])

However, I also see this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ and it seems there is 2.5/2.6 version available. I click "New features with Apache 2.5/2.6" link in the page, but get "page not found" error. So, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you're looking at unreleased versions

Answer (score 3):

Apache httpd uses the classic three numbers versioning scheme

```
Major.Minor.Patchlevel
```

and uses the Minor version number to distinguish between development versions (odd Minor number) and stable, released versions (even Minor number).

1. So 2.4.52 is the most recent released version as of the time of this writing.
2. The 2.5.x versions also exist, being in-progress unstable and unreleased development versions targetted at developers only. Once the 2.5 series matures and is considered to be ready for a release, it will become the 2.6 stable series, successor of the 2.4 stable series. (Just as the 2.4 series is the successor of the 2.2 series, with all 2.3.x versions being unstable development versions leading up to 2.4.0.)
3. There is not version 2.6.x yet, as development hasn't finished so far.

Unfortunately, I could not find any official informatin on the Apache httpd website detailing this.